# Frequently disconnections of wifi on lenovo yoga 2

Tags: wireless

Hello my wifi had started to disconnect it worked perfectly one week ago and now I cant do anything on other devices its working (mac,android). Any suggestions?

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0611]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

sudo lshw -c network

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 14:2d:27:f2:1d:11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:18 memory:b0400000-b0407fff
```

rfkill list all:

```
 0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
    2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Open up a terminal with ctrl + alt + t and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/686642/edit) your question with the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` ,  `lshw -c network` and `rfkill list all`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download [this](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) driver

make sure it's unzipped on your desktop then open terminal and type these commands:

```
cd Desktop
```

then

```
cd rtlwifi_new-master
```

then

```
sudo make install
```

Reboot after installation has finished.

Comment: Nothing changed. What did that to my wifi? I forgot to tell that when i turn wifi off and turn it on internet works for some seconds.

Comment: That includes the driver for BCM43142. Exact same one i'm using at the moment. Did it install ok without errors?

Comment: Yes. Everything was fine. Oh what can be wrong :/ its soo flustrating :( ..... Oh wait its working i will wait some minute and if everithing will be fine i will mark this answer solved :)

Comment: Ok its not disconnecting but its slower than week ago nevermind you helped me so thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: One question. Can i remove that file from my desktop?

Comment: Yes if it's installed you can delete it. But every time you update your kernal you will need to reinstall it so maybe bookmark the driver download page :)

Comment: @user3396072 Your accept of this answer is wrong. That Realtek driver can't do anything good to your Broadcom adapter.