# Wifi keeps disconecting on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless

I totally new on linux OS, just installed ubuntu yesterday. So far I faced problem with wifi, I'll try explane whats wrong. First, this is info about my wlan card:

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 30:10:b3:46:31:cf
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.1.65 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:19 memory:f7800000-f7807fff
```

So far I installed drivers using `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` , also I turned off power management for wlan, now its says OFF when using `iwconfig` command. Also I tried disabling ipv6. But intresting fact and I dont know if it really this that when I come to my router wifi not disconnecting, but when I go to my room and I get 2-3 bars of signal it starts disconnecting... I dont know, maybe is just coincidence... on windows 10 there was no problem with wifi signal and disconnecting... Maybe its some trigger that for poorer connection it starts disconnecting?

output of `rfkill list all` :

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Open up a terminal with ctrl + alt + t and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/686998/edit) your question with the output of  `rfkill list all`

Comment: next thing to check is on your wifi router, is the preamble is long or short? If your network is 'noisy' use long preamble.

Comment: Follow the answer on the page here [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/686642/frequently-disconnections-of-wifi-on-lenovo-yoga-2/686652#686652) It is for the same BCM43142 driver.

Comment: @William Please do not suggest Realtek drivers for Broadcom devices.

Comment: @AizuddinZali  Can you tell me more about this thing? I have TP-Link few years old router. And why all other windows computers, andoird smartphones not having disconnecting issue due long range? I'm able using just fine with my LG G2  just fine at twice longer distance from router :/

Answer (score 0):

First of all , if you are new to Linux , don't mess up or manually install drivers.

I am also using same BCM43142 chip. I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 yesterday after 2 months of continuous use of Ubuntu 14.04 . Instead of  manually downloading that drivers , if you used "proprietary" devices given in *System-Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers* , you wifi chip should work fine. Look at these articles : [article1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr) and [article2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr) . They will probably solve your problem.
[image]

Comment: It looks like the proprietary driver is already installed.

Comment: @Pilot6 may be he installed much newer bcmwl-kernel-source and that's why he is having problem.

Comment: That may be the case.

Comment: so if I messed up with drivers, can I somehow uninstall them and then clean install right one?

Comment: I discover intresting thing... when my connection is about 3bars internet working fine, no disconnects, but when it goes to 1-2bars, little lower then stable 3bars and internet connection goes down... on windows I can stable browse internet even with 1bar :/ could be this thing in linux possible? maybe there is some rules that block internet connection with poor internet?

Comment: @PauliusJanulevicius , [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr?lq=1) will help you out.